# Interesting JavasSript obfuscation method -- unable to decode it

Tags: javascript, encryption, obfuscation

I came across this interesting JavaScript file... I cannot seem to decode it... any ideas? Or is it actually encrypted?

http://pastebin.com/nRLr4hPY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In console:
paste in the first section up to the eval

```
_=" \u0009  .....         ";
```

second part replace the `eval` with `unescape` in the console and run it

```
unescape("_\u005f=\u0027';f\u006fr(i\u003d0;i<\u005f.l\u0065ng\u0074h;\u0069+\u002b)\u005f_+=S\u0074rin\u0067.\u0066r\u006fm\u0043harC\u006fde(\u005f.c\u0068a\u0072Co\u0064e\u0041t(i)\u005e3);e\u0076\u0061l(\u005f_)");
```

should give you this:

```
"__='';for(i=0;i<_.length;i++)__+=String.fromCharCode(_.charCodeAt(i)^3);eval(__)"
```

change the `eval` in the new code to `console.log` and run it

```
__='';for(i=0;i<_.length;i++)__+=String.fromCharCode(_.charCodeAt(i)^3);console.log(__)
```

take the output in the console and put it in [js beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and it gives you [the code](http://pastebin.com/PKJxsHbf)

This is not secure and took <30 seconds to get the code.

Comment: Thanks! It took me a while but I ended up at the same solution. I used document.write() instead. My only question is: whats is the last part of the code for? Is it the part that decodes the document recursively?

EDIT: Looks like its just added obfuscation

Comment: It is just a string added to the end to add confusion. They could have shrinked the code down to make it unreadable, but they did not do that.

Answer (score 2):

It's unicode.  Use

```
unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) );
```

to get it in it's normal form.  It's still obfuscated, but that'll get you started.

Comment: Thanks those two functions helped, the especially the unescape.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though it's encoded in unicode.  The thing that gave it away is at the bottom where it parses through that giant mess of stuff and decodes it and then it looks like it runs it through an `eval( )`.

If you wanted to decrypt it, you could run it through the function at the bottom and try to capture the output.

But no, it's not actually encrypted.  With enough patience, you can get the actual code out.  Otherwise, the browser would choke on it.  They can't decrypt encrypted javascript any more than you can without a key.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the \u was either unicode or some unsigned value.